# Making sticky rice without rice cooker

Tags: rice, rice-cooker, sticky-rice

I know that a rice cooker is the easiest way to make sticky rice, because of the way it is steamed. However, I don't have a rice cooker: what is the most effective way to make sticky rice using regular kitchen tools and appliances, i.e. ones which most people would have? (I am not against getting a rice cooker: I just don't want to invest in an appliance which I would probably not use that frequently. So I'm interested in learning how to make sticky rice with your average kitchen tools and appliances.)

Comment: I like to do it in a big bowl in a microwave.  Does that count as "regular pots and pans"?

Comment: Do you have a splatter guard, by any chance? Or can you easily acquire one?

Comment: @DavidWallace Yes I think that does! I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall I do not but I'm sure I could get one. I mostly don't want to get kitchen tools that are so specialized, i.e. I would rarely use them.

Comment: Well, splatter guards are very cheap.

Answer (score 2):

You can replicate a Thai rice steamer with a deep frying pan, a splatter guard, and a heatproof bowl. Just place a mound of soaked glutinous rice in the centre of the splatter guard over simmering water, then place the bowl on top, and steam for about 20-30 minutes, turning the mound over once or twice to ensure even cooking.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything but a pot, lid, and spoon. The easiest way is to cheat and add some sugar, probably 1/4 cup for every cup of rice.

First you wash the rice several times, stir it around and squish it a bit to get the external layer of starch off. Once the water comes out clear you don't need to wash it anymore. Next add water and the sugar, bring it to a boil, then lower it to low heat. Stir it every 3-5 minutes until the rice is done.

Comment: What is the point of adding sugar?

Comment: Rice is starch, and starches are chains of sugars. When you make sticky rice the hard way some of the rice's starch gets converted to simple sugars which make the rice sticky. Adding sugar means you don't have to convert starches to simple sugars, it's essentially a cheat.